# Parsing text file to sql database using python

Tags: python, sql, database, parsing, text-files

extreme python/sql beginner here. I've looked around for some help with this but wasn't able to find exactly what I need- would really appreciate any assistance.

As the title indicates, I have a very large text file that I want to parse into a sql database preferably using python. The text file is set up as so:

```
#Parent field 1.1
child 1.1
child 1.1 continued

# Parent field 1.2
child 1.2

# Parent field 1.3
child 1.3 text
child 1.3 text
more child 1.3 text

...

# Parent field 1.88
child 1.88

#Parent field 2.1
child 2.1

etc...
```

Some key points about the list:

- the first field (i.e. 1.1, 2.1) has no space after the #
- the length of each child row has variable character lengths and line breaks but there is  always an empty line before the next parent
- there are 88 fields for each parent
- there are hundreds of parent fields

Now, I'd like each parent field (1.1, 1.2, 1.3 --> .88) to be a column and the rows populated by subsequent numbers (2.1, 3.1 -->100s)

Could someone help me set up a python script and give me some direction of how to begin parsing? Let me know if I haven't explained the task properly and I'll promptly provide more details.

Thanks so much!

Ben

EDIT: I just realized that the # of columns is NOT constant 88, it is variable

Comment: Are you dynamically creating database tables dependent upon the contents of the text file?  Ie, will the number of columns or column type/size vary?  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean when you say that there are 88 fields for each parent yet hundreds of parent fields?  It sounds like each 88 parents = 88 columns, but are there multiple tables being inserted into here?

Comment: Hi willOEM, thanks for your response. Yes, the 88 represents the # of columns, but I just realized that the 88 IS NOT constant for each parent, it is variable. How much of a problem will this pose?

Comment: If you are parsing this data into a single table, with a set maximum number of columns with set widths, then it is not an issue if data for each column is not present in every row.  If we are talking about fluctuating table definitions, then this is a trickier problem.  How much of a problem will depend on the DBMS and Python module you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

1. From the description it seems like you aim at your data being denormalized in one table. This is generally not a good idea. Split your data into two tables: PARENT and CHILDREN.
   PARENT should contain ID and CHILDREN should have at least two columns: PARENT_ID and CHILD_VALUE (or smth like it) with PARENT_ID being ID of a parent, whether linked explicitly as foreign key DB construct or not (depending on database). Then, while parsing, INSERT into table CHILDREN relevant record with VALUES("1.1", "1.1childA"), VALUES("1.1", "1.1childB") and so on.
2. parsing should be trivial: iterate line by line and on "parent" line change parent_id and INSERT into PARENT and read child rows as it goes and INSERT those into CHILDREN table. You could also do it in two passes.

Smth like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

parent=''
child=''

for line in open('input.txt'):
        if line.find('#Parent') > -1 or line.find('# Parent') > -1:
                parent = field_extract(line) # fun where you extract parent value
                parent_id = ... # write it down or generate
                # INSERT into PARENT
        elif line:
                child = field_extract(line)
                # INSERT into CHILDREN with parent_id and child values
```

Although... I shudder when I see smth so primitive. I'd urge you to learn Pyparsing module, absolutely great for this kind of work.

Comment: thank you very much, i'll definitely try out this 2 step process.

Comment: @ben: P.S. I'm not sure how familiar you are with SQL but two tables here give you quite a bit of flexibility: if you have PARENT table with 88 columns and CHILDREN table with values, you could do clever SELECT queries with JOINs on PARENT and CHILDREN tables, that's exactly what SQL databases are designed for to perform well. The downside is you have to learn how to use JOINs. :-)

Comment: thanks again. i just realized that the 88 column # is not absolute and changes based on each parent. will that pose a problem?

also I should mention that the fields are not all named #parent but different for each, is there a way to say line.find # + " " +text vs # + text?

Comment: 1. 88 columns problem: that should not be a problem if all you have are unfilled fields: just insert NULLs there. However, if *type* changes that is more of a problem as a column can have only one type. Google's BigTable does not have this sort of limitation but I'm assuming you do not have GAE sitting on your shelf. :-) 2. how are fields different exactly? if it's just a space but values can be found you could do `parvals = line.split(' ')` first and then `''.join(parvals)` and get uniformized parent identifier.

Comment: However, if parent ids change in structure from parent row to parent row, it might be regex time. (and like JWZ says, then you have two problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

you should look into **file handling** in python.

the `open() , .readlines()` methods and lists will help you **alot**.

for example:

```
f = open("NAMEOFTXTFILE.TXT","r") #r for read, w for write, a for append.
cell = f.readlines() # Displays the content in a list
f.seek(0) # Just takes the cursor to the first cell (start of document)
print cell[2] # Prints the word or letter in the second cell.
```

then from there, you can send `cell[2]` with sql statements.

Comment: The OP wrote smth about the file being big. If it's truly big, `.readlines` is not a good idea as it will try to read entire file into memory. Better go line by line if you can and here it appears you can.

Comment: hi mrkafk, thanks very much:-) It is very big so I will try to do it line by line